# Subtract column 1 and column 2 the total is in column 3

Tags: mysql

I have a database like this

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
   10    |    6     | i want the total here
```

What will be the SQL Query in this?
I want to subtract the column 1 and column 2 then the column 3 will be the total

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2, col1-col2 AS col3 ...`

Comment: Surprising isn't it? In order to subtract one value from another, one uses the minus sign, just like in any programming language. Didn't that come to mind? Didn't that show up in Google for "subtract sql"? Haven't you even tried anything? I am baffled you come here with such a question.

Answer (score 0):

If You need an update statement, You may try below query -

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET COL3 = COL1-COL2;
```